# Параферналия. Правильно ли использовано слово в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, переводы

[*Сама Трейси любила толстые книжки Джеки Коллинз. Она бы никому не обмолвилась — это ее тайный порок, невыразимое удовольствие, как порнография (или «Дисней»). Ребенку подойдет едва ли, и Трейси на ходу сочинила сказку про бедную маленькую принцессу Кортни — у нее была злая мать, а потом ее спасла очень добрая мачеха.] **Трейси щедро подсыпала мифологической параферналии — прялок и гномов, — и, когда на ножку принцессы Кортни примеряли стеклянную туфельку, настоящая Кортни уже спала.***
[К. Аткинсон. Чуть свет, с собакою вдвоем](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=158993&p=19)  (перевод с английского А. Грызуновой)

Читала книгу; споткнулась на слове **параферналия** (оно мне было неизвестно); порылась в словарях — просветление не пришло.
Подскажите, грамотно ли употреблено редкое слово?
(Отдельно: смущает пунктуация в предложении. Как вы считаете — правильна ли она?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Проверка пунктуации**

Думаю, что здесь нужно использовать только одно тире (оформление обособленного приложения, а не вставки).

Трейси щедро подсыпала мифологической **параферналии — прялок и гномов,**  и, когда на ножку принцессы Кортни примеряли стеклянную туфельку, настоящая Кортни уже спала.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:
1) **если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая:** Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, то понял бы источник ошибки;

**2) Параферналии**

Я думаю, что гномы сюда не подойдут, так как к параферналиям относятся предметы.

Можно посмотреть, как она выглядят в магазине (это только часть атрибутики) http://mangobazar.ru/

Comment: Вот оно! Я видела словарные определения, но не смогла решить — относятся ли гномы (они ведь одушевленные?) к параферналии.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за интересные вопросы, которые Вы нам задаете. Поздравляю Вас с праздником и надеюсь на сотрудничество в новом году

Comment: Спасибо за поздравления и положительные отзывы. И я Вам кланяюсь.

Answer (score 1):

> **Параферналия** (от греч. παράφερνα — parapherna) — совокупность снаряжения, оборудования, принадлежностей, используемых для занятий
>   определенного рода, и, как следствие, являющихся отличительными
>   чертами этих занятий.
>
> **Параферналия**, *книжн.* Предмет как характерная принадлежность какой-либо сферы бытования, применения и т. п.; атрибут.

В предложении слово на месте, читай: ***мифологической атрибутики***.

А откудова отсчитывать предложение с пунктуацией?

Возьмём всё, с квадратными скобками тож.

> Сама Трейси любила толстые книжки Джеки Коллинз. Она бы никому не
>   обмолвилась — это ее тайный порок, невыразимое удовольствие, как
>   порнография (или «Дисней»). Ребенку подойдет едва ли, и Трейси на ходу
>   сочинила сказку про бедную маленькую принцессу Кортни — у нее была
>   злая мать, а потом ее спасла очень добрая мачеха. Трейси щедро
>   подсыпала мифологической параферналии — прялок и гномов, — и, когда на
>   ножку принцессы Кортни примеряли стеклянную туфельку, настоящая Кортни
>   уже спала.

Может быть и так (как есть), можно - нелюбителям тире - поменять оное на двоеточие *(про бедную маленькую принцессу Кортни: у нее была...)*; можно обойтись одной запятой после *гномов*, но в переводческую (=авторскую) пунктуацию вмешиваться нет нужды.

Запятые все на своих местах.

Comment: С Новым годом, Галина! Здоровья и позитива! (В вопросе: имеется в виду **_выделенное_** предложение.)

Comment: С новым! ))) Так я уж про всё сказала, чохом. В выделенном можно оставить гномов с одной запятой, без тире, то есть разрушить слышимую переводчиком вставку в двух тире. Всё остальное в порядке.